# Movie about idyllic town being "generated" by a person, sinkholes appear when she's not concentrating

Tags: identify-this-movie

I probably watched this movie about 10+ years ago, language was English. 
I'm not sure if I've remembered all of this entirely correctly.

Movie starts out with the main character growing up in this picture-perfect little town. There are public announcement speakers in the town, and all is well except the main character's mother is always sick/almost comatose.

But weird stuff happens in the town. A sinkhole appears in one area of the town and swallows up a kid (perhaps leaving their tricycle?). The PA Speakers say there's nothing to worry about and say to avoid the area. The sinkhole then later just disappears.

Turns out that the mother who is always comatose is somehow keeping the town "alive" or structurally sound, and when she comes out of her stupor for a bit then the sink holes appear, but now she's getting old and so they're appearing anyway.

Can't remember much more, but think it might have been some dream that she and her husband cooked up to raise their son in the perfect environment, and I think in the end the main character decides that he has to make the sacrifice to take over from his mother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Prisoner Mini-Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner_%282009_miniseries%29)

A dreaming woman sustains a town populated by the sub-conscious avatars of people from the real world. Here is the description of the final episode.

Episode 6 "Checkmate":

> 6 encounters new arrivals, which contradicts claims that no world exists. 2 shows off new houses, indicating the village is expanding. This is later revealed to be to increase pressure on 6 to replace 2 to stop the holes from destroying the village. 6 confronts 2 about the newcomers, but soon forgets as 2 reveals he has afflicted 6 with a disease that will kill him. 6 confronts 11–12 when he meets him at 909's grave and again at the Go Inside bar. 11–12 is unable to reconcile himself to his false identity. He proceeds to smother his dreaming mother and hang himself.
>
> In New York, Michael is escorted to a car so he may meet "Mr. Curtis". Events in New York and The Village begin to parallel each other. Michael is aware of this. 6's determination does not waver in the face of death and 2 allows him to live. However, 2 intends to use 6's nobility to finally control him. In New York, Curtis, who is also 2, introduces Michael to Curtis' wife, who seems to be in a sort of waking dream. He reveals the Village's purpose to 6. Curtis explains that the Village is a form of therapy used to help people that Summakor has identified, although without regard to those people's desires. It exists within the mind of his wife, who 'discovered' the Village—a dream present in everyone at a level of consciousness deeper than the subconscious—and was its first inhabitant. Michael was drawn into the village because he worked so well at Summakor, finding people who needed 'help', and Curtis does not want Michael to resign. It is clear that Curtis' son in the Village is the only Village resident not based on real people in the real world. This has drained his "mother", the dreamer. Curtis' use of the Village was to work through their trauma of being childless but the creation of the son threatened the Village's continued existence. Neither could bring themselves to kill their son and over the 6 episodes we see him provided with sufficient rope (inhuman behaviour including murder) that he hangs himself.
>
> At his son's funeral, 2 rallies the Villagers and tells them 6 is the only solution to the holes, while in New York, Curtis introduces Michael to Sara, the real world counterpart of 313, who is homeless and insane because of childhood trauma. Michael is overcome with his humanity and desire to help Sara and the villagers and replaces Curtis as the head of Summakor. In The Village, 6 becomes the new 2, while 313 becomes the dreamer who keeps the Village in existence, freeing Curtis' wife from being the dreamer and allowing her to return to the real world. 6 begins planning how to 'do The Village right' and 313, still very ill, sheds a tear, knowing that number 2 finally has won and 6 is now stuck in The Village for good.

Comment: Thanks! I think this must be it. Comparing my description to yours, I see that I had only very fuzzy recollections of it, I probably only watched the last episode. I'll watch it again now that I know what it's called!